How to create rich models without depending on infrastructure? (Database or external services)
I'm grappling with a challenge in domain-driven design (DDD) regarding achieving a Rich Model.
In complex systems, it often feels nearly impossible to execute most business rules without access to database information or external services.
How can one realistically achieve a Rich Model under these circumstances? What strategies or methodologies can be employed to maintain domain purity while still integrating essential data dependencies in DDD? Despite the ideal scenarios depicted in books, the practical implementation seems significantly challenging.
Additionally, if I rely on services, I find that most business rules tend to migrate there rather than remaining in the domain. How can I strike a balance to ensure that crucial business logic remains within the domain model?"

Warning: don't be fooled by toy examples into believing that this is supposed to be easy....


it often feels nearly impossible to execute most business rules without access to database information or external services. How can one realistically achieve a Rich Model under these circumstances?

Separation of concerns.  The responsibility of the "Rich Model" is the manipulation of information in local data structures.  Copying remote information into local data structures, or copying information from local data structures to somewhere else, are concerns that are handled outside of the domain model (in domain driven design language, these are typically concerns that appear in the "application layer", rather than in the "domain layer").
If you think in terms of the client/server model (see Wirfs-Brock), we're designing a protocol that allows an application client (which knows all about how to fetch information, or where to send it) with a domain model server (which knows all about computing things using local information).
Cory Benfield describes a similar separation in his talk about building protocol libraries; or more generally look into Sans I/O.

How can I strike a balance to ensure that crucial business logic remains within the domain model?

Putting things where they belong is primarily the skill of prioritizing discipline over expediency.
One trick is to make sure that you have tests for all of your business logic, and that those tests do NOT have any dependencies on things other than the domain model (the domain model, in all its complexity, acting on information provided by the test; think "sociable test" rather than "solitary" or "unit" test).
Of course, that trick also requires discipline.
